# Как вывести данные страницы Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mvc

Роут:

```
Route::get('/page/{url}', 'PageController@page')->where('url', '[a-z]+');
```

Контроллер:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Category;
use App\Page;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PageController extends Controller
{

    protected $catalog;
    protected $page;

    public function __construct()
    {
       // Коллекция всех категорий
      $this->category = Category::all();
      // Коллекция всех страниц
      $this->page = Page::all();
    }

    public function page(Page $singlePage) {
        $page_show = $singlePage;
        $catalog = $this->category;
        $page = $this->page;
        $title = $page_show->title;
        echo $title;
        var_dump($page_show);

        return view('page', ['catalog' => $catalog, 'page_show' => $page_show, 'page' => $page, 'title' => $title]);
    }
}
```

Модель:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Page extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'pages';

    public function getRouteKeyName()
        {
            return 'url';
        }
}
```

Подскажите что я делаю не так? Вот вар дамп:

```
object(App\Page)#265 (27) { ["table":protected]=> string(5) "pages" ["singlePage":protected]=> NULL ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(false) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["original":protected]=> array(0) { } ["changes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } }
```

attributes должен быть не пустой массив, но почему он пустой? Заранее спасибо за ответы

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePagesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('pages');
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас в модели точно есть колонка url в $fillable массиве и со значением, которое вы передаёте в запрос?

Comment: Модель я скинул, это весь код модели, проблема в ней?

Comment: Добавьте миграцию для страницы, а то не понятно какие колонки там есть.

Comment: Добавил миграцию

Comment: Вам нужно заполнить массив [$fiilable](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) полями к которым вы хотите доступ. Пример: protected $fillable = ['title'] - с этим вы сможете оперировать через $singlePage->title, и она будет в аттрибутах объекта.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как заполнить, это в моделе? protected $fillable = ['title'] поставил в моделе и все равно не выводится title и в атрибутах нету.

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто, Вы создали переменную с названием:

```
protected $catalog
```

а в методе __construct() Вы обращаетесь к переменной с другим именем ($this->category = Category::all()), нужно определится с именем. Простая не внимательность, присущая всем творческим людям!)

Вот в этом участке кода:

```
class PageController extends Controller
{

    protected $catalog;
    protected $page;

    public function __construct()
    {
       // Коллекция всех категорий
      $this->category = Category::all();
      // Коллекция всех страниц
      $this->page = Page::all();
    }
```

Comment: Действительно ошибся с названием переенной. Спасибо. Но дело не в ней, по прежнему не выводится title, мне нужно что бы $title = $page_show->title; Выводило title

Answer (score 0):

Вот ещё нашёл:
Переменная $singlePage в методе page() это экземпляр класса "Page", чтобы получить значение title элемента из БД, нужно вызвать этот элемент так:

```
public function page(Page $singlePage) {
        $id = 3; // Вы должны указать ID нужного вам элемента
        $page_show = $singlePage->find($id);
        $title = $page_show->title;

        $catalog = $this->category;
        $page = $this->page;

        return view('page', ['title' => $title]);
    }
```

Comment: Вы должны указать ID нужного вам элемента, извините, но не буду эе я прописывать id постоянно, или как правильно подтянуть id выбранной страницы?